# Can a function of a vN algebra's projections "act like" the restriction of a state, but not be one?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $\mathcal{R}$ is a von Neumann algebra and  $\mathbb{P}_\mathcal{R}$ is the set of its projection operators. Because the linear span of $\mathbb{P}_\mathcal{R}$ is norm-dense in $\mathcal{R}$ (I'm assured this is the case) it seems reasonable that if a function "behaves like" the restriction to $\mathbb{P}_\mathcal{R}$ of a state on $\mathcal{R}$, then it must be one. Is this true?

To make this precise, call a real function $\phi : \mathbb{P}_\mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ "state-like" if:

(1) $\phi$ only takes values in $[0,1]$, and has value $1$ on the identity projection;

(2) $\phi$ is linear in the sense that if $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ are pairwise orthogonal, then $\phi(P_1 + \ldots + P_n) = \phi(P_1) + \ldots + \phi(P_n)$;

(3) $\phi$ is continuous with respect to the operator norm topology.

**If $\phi$ is a state-like function on $\mathbb{P}_\mathcal{R}$, must it extend to a state on $\mathcal{R}$?**

If the answer is "yes," the first step in proving it is presumably to show that $\phi$ extends to a unique positive linear functional $\phi^+$ on the linear span of $\mathbb{P}_\mathcal{R}$. You would define

$\phi^+(c_0 P_0 + \ldots + c_n P_n) \equiv c_0 \phi(P_0) + \ldots c_n \phi(P_n),$

and then show that this extension of $\phi$ is *well*-defined. That is, you'd show that if $T \in \mathcal{R}$ can be decomposed in two distinct ways as linear combinations of projections, then the $\phi^+$ values calculated by the above definition are the same for both.  But I haven't been able to show this -- it's frustrating because I haven't been able to pin down a "normal form" or "canonical form" for a linear combination of projections. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does Gleason’s Theorem (and its generalizations) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I need, thank you! The most directly applicable form seems to be here -- https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3153/29eb03d7fb6de793b5edd6d78cfbf7137957.pdf . The upshot is that the answer to my question is affirmative, so long as $\mathcal{R}$ has no direct summand of type $I_2$.

Comment: also came across this quote: "Does an analogue of Gleason’s Theorem hold for von Neumann algebras not
isomorphic to B(H)? The answer is positive, but nearly twenty years of work were needed to work out all the details." Glad I decided not to plow ahead by myself ...